# kable single column data frame produces a heading instead of table

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

In R, if you create a data frame with a single column, then try to print it into an R Markdown document, it gets turned into a heading and plain text instead of an actual table.

For example, if your R Markdown document contains this code:

````
# A Heading

```{r, results='asis'}
library("knitr")
test_df <- data.frame("test")
kable(test_df)

test_df_2 <-data.frame(first = "one", second = "two")
kable(test_df_2)
```
````

It gets converted into this Markdown:

````
# A Heading


```r
test_df <- data.frame("test")
kable(test_df)
```



X.test. 
--------
test    

```r
test_df_2 <-data.frame(first = "one", second = "two")
kable(test_df_2)
```



first   second 
------  -------
one     two
````

Which renders this output:

[image]

This makes sense, because the [documentation on Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header) considers `-------------` to be an H2 second level heading. However, this is not the case for `------  -------`, which gets correctly rendered into a table.

Is this a bug? Is the only solution to include at least two columns?

Comment: Looks like a bug in kable. Maybe try A different package? From knitr's help, the kable section states:

"See Also
Other R packages such as xtable and tables for HTML and LaTeX tables, and ascii and pander for different flavors of markdown output and some advanced features and table styles."

EG: pander supports pipe table format, which would bypass this bug

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this question, but it is a totally valid question with a reproducible example. Also asked here: https://github.com/yihui/printr/issues/24 It is a bug of `knitr::kable()` that I don't have time to fix yet.

Comment: For the moment I am just adding a second empty column with '.' or similar as the column name.